# Adding background image to button in SWT

Tags: java, button, swt, background-image

Can anyone please tell me how to add background image to a button in SWT? I need something like in the attachment. 
[image: bg_image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, `Button` isn't the best starting point if you basically want to *draw* a completely different type of button. You can however, create your own widget using [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) tutorial. I wrote an example here:

```
public class ImageButton extends Composite
{
    private Color   textColor;
    private Image   image;
    private String  text;
    private int     width;
    private int     height;

    public ImageButton(Composite parent, int style)
    {
        super(parent, style);

        textColor = Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);

        /* Add dispose listener for the image */
        addListener(SWT.Dispose, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                if (image != null)
                    image.dispose();
            }
        });

        /* Add custom paint listener that paints the stars */
        addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e)
            {
                paintControl(e);
            }
        });

        /* Listen for click events */
        addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                System.out.println("Click");
            }
        });
    }

    private void paintControl(Event event)
    {
        GC gc = event.gc;

        if (image != null)
        {
            gc.drawImage(image, 1, 1);
            Point textSize = gc.textExtent(text);
            gc.setForeground(textColor);
            gc.drawText(text, (width - textSize.x) / 2 + 1, (height - textSize.y) / 2 + 1, true);
        }
    }

    public void setImage(Image image)
    {
        this.image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), image, SWT.IMAGE_COPY);
        width = image.getBounds().width;
        height = image.getBounds().height;
        redraw();
    }

    public void setText(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
        redraw();
    }

    @Override
    public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed)
    {
        int overallWidth = width;
        int overallHeight = height;

        /* Consider hints */
        if (wHint != SWT.DEFAULT && wHint < overallWidth)
            overallWidth = wHint;

        if (hHint != SWT.DEFAULT && hHint < overallHeight)
            overallHeight = hHint;

        /* Return computed dimensions plus border */
        return new Point(overallWidth + 2, overallHeight + 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        ImageButton button = new ImageButton(shell, SWT.NONE);
        button.setImage(new Image(display, "button.png"));
        button.setText("Button");

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

---

Of course you'd have to take care of different states like `pressed`, `hover` and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much Baz. This is exactly what I was looking for. But this image button doesn't have the same behaviour of Button like the press behaviour while it is clicked. Could you please tell me how this can be achieved? Which event should I override?

Comment: @JayakrishnanSalim Well, you'll have to listen for `SWT.MouseDown` and `SWT.MouseUp` and trigger a redraw with a different `Image`. Be sure to `dispose()` all `Image`s you create though.

Comment: @JayakrishnanSalim That what exactly will work? And what exactly didn't work? It might be worth opening a new question rather than discussing this in the comment section.

Comment: I have a small upload image which I need to display in each row of a list. I used the same code snippet which you shared and everything worked fine. 
But when the number of rows increased to 1000 I got 'org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles' exception.

I used Sleak.java and found that the image objects are around 1400.

Comment: @JayakrishnanSalim If all of the buttons use the same image, then make them all use the same `Image` object. Dispose that one on your main code and remove the listener for `SWT.Dispose` from my code above.

Comment: I am reusing the same Image object. But still I am having the issue. Can you please tell me what should be the dispose logic in my case?

Comment: @JayakrishnanSalim Then there has to be another problem somewhere in your code. Please create a new question and post the relevant parts of your code. Or even better: create a minimal example that shows your problem.

Comment: Already created. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007294/how-to-reuse-images-in-swt