# SWT - a lot of attempts to create my own design button

Tags: java, button, swt, label, listener

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to use my own design buttons in my application.

In the beginning I tried to create a button and to use setImage() method to cover the button with my own design image. no matter what I tried I never succeeded to cover the hole button, the border of the old button always blinked from behind, or when I resized the shell my button image became too small to cover the old button.

I tryied to color the background of the old button, but it turns out that setBackground() method doesn't work on buttons. 
I have figured out that even though setBackground() doesn't work on button, it doe's work on lables. 
 So now I'm to turn a label to a clickable object by adding some kind of listener to him, but I can’t find a listener that can generate a click event for labels (MouseListener is only sensitive for double click)
 I will be glad to get some help with figuring out a better way do achive my goal, or a appropriate listener.

Im adding a link to the photo of the button. this photo show how the button looks when I strech the shell to maximum. my goal is to make the grey parts disappear.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VgmT.jpg 
thanks.

Comment: You might what to look at [Opal](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/) the OButton may do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. But I'm still Interested about the traditional way to do that.

Comment: You can use MouseListener, you need to listen for a mouse down followed by a mouse up. You can see all this in the OButton source.

Comment: Thanks, its working with mouse down.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23731024/1449199) answer. Basically, create your own custom button instead of the `Button` class. It's not flexible enough for what you want to do.