# How to reuse images in SWT

Tags: java, image, swt, reusability

I have a list of items which I display in a grid layout. Each row have couple of image buttons. When the row count reached over 1000 I am getting `org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles` exception.

I used `Sleak.java` and found that there have been a number of images in the memory. Is it possible to reuse these buttons somehow?

Below is the statistics from `Sleak`.

Colors: 8
Cursors: 6
Fonts: 19
Images: 1317

Code:

```
private void looper(List<File> dicomFiles, int start, int stop, int toShow){
        for(int i=start; i<stop; i++){
            File dicomFile = dicomFiles.get(i);
            Composite rowComposite = new Composite(dicomFilecomposite, SWT.None);
            rowComposite.setLayout(configRowCompositeLayout());
            rowComposite.setLayoutData(getRowCompositeGridData());
            rowComposite.setBackground(Colors.CELL_BG_COLOR);
            Label dicomFIleLabel = new Label(rowComposite, SWT.NULL);
            dicomFIleLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData());
            dicomFIleLabel.setText(dicomFile.getName());
            dicomFIleLabel.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
            dicomFIleLabel.setFont(FONT_10);
            Label fileSizeLabel = new Label(rowComposite, SWT.None);
            fileSizeLabel.setText((dicomFile.length() / 1000)+" "+Const.KB_LABEL);
            fileSizeLabel.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
            Composite progBarLabelComposite = new Composite(rowComposite, SWT.None);
            progBarLabelComposite.setLayout(new RowLayout());
            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(progBarLabelComposite, SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.SMOOTH);
            progressBar.setVisible(true);
            Label progressPercentageLabel = new Label(progBarLabelComposite, SWT.None);
            progressPercentageLabel.setText(Const.INITIAL_PROGBAR_PERCENTAGE);
            progressPercentageLabel.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
            Composite btnWrapperComposite = new Composite(rowComposite, SWT.None);
            btnWrapperComposite.setLayout(configZeroMarginLayout(true));
            GridData btnWrapperCompositeGridData = new GridData();
            btnWrapperCompositeGridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.END;
            btnWrapperCompositeGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
            btnWrapperComposite.setLayoutData(btnWrapperCompositeGridData);
            Composite uploadCancelBtnComposite = new Composite(btnWrapperComposite, SWT.None);
            uploadCancelBtnComposite.setLayout(new RowLayout());
            Composite uploadBtnComposite = new Composite(uploadCancelBtnComposite, SWT.NULL);
            uploadBtnComposite.setLayout(configZeroMarginLayout(false));
            ImageButton uploadButton = new ImageButton(uploadBtnComposite, SWT.PUSH);
            uploadButton.setImage(Const.UPLOAD_BTN_BG_IMAGE);
            uploadButton.setListener(MainShell.this);
            uploadButton.setCursor(HAND_CURSOR);
            uploadButton.setToolTipText(Const.UPLOAD_LABEL);
            ImageButton cancelButton = new ImageButton(uploadCancelBtnComposite, SWT.PUSH);
            cancelButton.setImage(Const.DELETE_BTN_BG_IMAGE);
            cancelButton.setListener(MainShell.this);
            cancelButton.setCursor(HAND_CURSOR);
            cancelButton.setToolTipText(Const.DELETE_LABEL);
            FileUploadData fileUploadData = loadFileUploadData(progBarLabelComposite, dicomFilecomposite, dicomFile, progressBar, progressPercentageLabel);
            uploadButton.setData(fileUploadData);
            uploadButton.setData(IMG_BTN_DATA_KEY, Const.UPLOAD_LABEL);
            uploadButtons.add(uploadButton);
            fileUploadDatas.add(fileUploadData);
            cancelButton.setData(fileUploadData);
            cancelButton.setData(IMG_BTN_DATA_KEY, Const.DELETE_LABEL);
            loadSeparatorField(rowComposite);
        }
    }
```

In these two lines are where the issue is occurring in my understanding.

```
ImageButton uploadButton = new ImageButton(uploadBtnComposite, SWT.PUSH);
    ImageButton cancelButton = new ImageButton(uploadCancelBtnComposite, SWT.PUSH);
```

Comment: Please post your code or ideally a minimal example that shows your problem. If you really are reusing the image, then there has to be another problem in your code.

Comment: Ok, I don't see a memory leak in that code. Now the question is **why** do you need that many buttons. **What** are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What my app does is, it picks a particular type of files from a folder , list them in the UI and when the user clicks the upload button, uploads them to the server. 
These buttons are for uploading individual files to server. So it will be there for each row in the list.

Comment: Why not have a list with all the files, allow multiple selection and have one upload button?

Comment: I just done that but in that case also I got this issue. I could list down more number of files than previous case but the issue still occurred. :(

Comment: Well, then there really is something wrong somewhere else in your code. Track down all occurrences of `Image`, `Font`, `Color`, etc. that you create yourself and make sure your reuse them, and `dispose()` them when not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In SWT you can not reuse buttons however you can reuse images. Write a singleton class say ImageCache and cache all the images in it and fetch images from this class wherever required.
I faced the same problem and solved it this way.
Also create your custom dispose methods in your UI components and dispose UI components yourself because SWT does not disposes them properly and resources leak in most cases.

SWT best practice says that "all resources must be cached" so your fonts, colors, images must be cached and used properly in respective ItemRenderers.

Comment: I am also doing the same. The 'Image' objects are cached in a common file. Still no use. :(

Comment: ImageButton uploadButton = new ImageButton(uploadBtnComposite, SWT.PUSH);
   uploadButton.setImage(Const.UPLOAD_BTN_BG_IMAGE);

private static final ImageData UPLOAD_BTN_BG_IMAGE_DATA = new ImageData(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("upload.png"));



public static final Image UPLOAD_BTN_BG_IMAGE = new Image(APP_DISPLAY, UPLOAD_BTN_BG_IMAGE_DATA);

Comment: Your are doing it right. With reference to your question it seems that you are creating 1317 different button and displaying them on UI. So the problem is a bit confusing, why do you need so many buttons? and how are you displaying them? Is it a SWT table with ItemEditor objects? For your specific problem, i need more data.

Comment: I am using just a grid layout and ScrolledComposite. I am not using SWT table. 
I need to show around 1500 rows in a ScrolledComposite. At first I show 50 rows and upon clicking a button I will add 50 more and so on.

Comment: OK, Seems pretty complex scenario, So the solution depends on cases. Case 1: When next button is pressed again and again, all the buttons are visible on UI (Hence buttons add up in previously visible buttons) For this case you can not do any memory optimization because all of the images are taking part in UI                      Case 2: You display 50 buttons, when user clicks Next, You update previous 50 buttons for new Images and handlers. In this case only 50 buttons will be visible on UI and will save memory.                  Remember that **Hiding** a UI component does not release memory.

Comment: So if you use a Scroll composite and draw several components on it, all the components will be in memory until view/editor is disposed.