# Java / SWT/ How to remove frame from button

Tags: java, image, button, swt

I used SWT interface builder to build my GUI. I have several buttons. How do I delete the frame (grey background and the border) from the button, so only the image is visible? Code for the button: `onButton = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);`

[image]

Help is very appreciated.

As request. This is how I set the Image for the button:

```
onButton.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(
            "C:\\Users\\dseek\\Desktop\\PanetHomeProxySwitch\\PlanetHomeProxySwitch\\src\\proxyEinschaltenGroupSmall@3x.png"));
```

Comment: Please show how you set the image to the button and also what the image itself looks like. A `Button` may not be the suitible widget for your purpose, maybe have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729981/adding-background-image-to-button-in-swt).

Comment: I have entered the requested edit.

Comment: Did you have a look if the link solves your problem?

Comment: I am taking a look right now

Comment: well it would solve my problem, but it would need me to completely rewrite my app...

Comment: And you're expecting this to be possible without work on your behalf? You used a button. A button has a certain look based on the OS. Setting an image to it will fit the image *inside* the button, but keep the buttons original look (the border). If you don't want it to look like an OS button, don't use a `Button`.

Comment: Yes. I got this and I thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: If you want to, you can answer with that and I will check, since my problem is solved as impossible.

Comment: Sorry if that sounded harsh. Hope you'll be able to rework your application to get the button you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible if you want to use a `Button` as your base widget.

The button is styled by the operating system, e.g. it will have a gray gradient and a dark rounded border on Windows.

Setting an image to it will unfortunately not replace this look, but rather just place your image inside that button. The border will remain.

I have, however posted [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23731024/1449199) that shows how to create your own widget that'll use the given image and act like a button. It's not a complete example, but it should get you started.

The result looks like this:

[image]